# Loading images via https after loading the css file via https

Tags: css, https

I have loaded a css file via https. However, the css file calls images via http. Here is a snippet of one of the images that is causing this problem. The image in question is nav1_bg.gif

```
#nav-bar { border-top:1px solid #2d444f; border-bottom:1px solid #2d444f; background:url(nav1_bg.gif) repeat-x 0 100% #666e73; padding:0 30px;  }
```

I would like to modify the css code so that it brings the images via https instead of http. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the absolute path https://www.yourdomain.com/nav1_bg.gif

Comment: Sjm. It still requests via http.